# Android: how to mimic the pane separator from Google Reader?

Tags: android

[image]

The Google Reader app has a nice shadow used to separate the two panes.  I am trying to recreate this with very limited success.  I am using the below xml, which gives the screen shot that follows.  Any advice on improving this?

vertshadowgradient.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
android:startColor="#ffffff"
android:centerColor="#e6e6e6"
android:endColor="#c8c8c8"
android:angle="0" />
</shape>
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <View android:id="@+id/divider" 
        android:background="@drawable/vertshadowgradient"
        android:layout_marginLeft="200dip"
        android:layout_width="10dip" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `hierarchyviewer` to find out how it is made in Google Reader http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-ui.html